How do you define $1$-cell identities and inverses in an unbiased bigroupoid/2-groupoid?
I am trying to unpack example 3.4.5 of Leinster's Higher Operads, Higher Categories (screengrab below) relating the an unbiased homotopy bigroupoid/2-groupoid of a topological space.
https://i.sstatic.net/0uEFHkCY.png
I first have a question about Leinster's definition of unbiased bicategory (screengrab below). Here he actually gives a lax definition but since it's homotopies we're interested we can assume the coherence 2-cells are invertable.
https://i.sstatic.net/JcKDKR2C.png
My first question is how do the $1$-cell identities work? My guess is you define them by the $0$-ary composition
\begin{align*}
   \circ_0 & : 1 \xrightarrow{\text{dfn}} \mathcal{B}(a,a)\\
           & :  * \mapsto 1_a,
\end{align*}
but I'm not sure where the unit coherence $2$-cells that would make this behave like an identity are hidden, e.g. $1_a\circ_1f \Rightarrow f$ and $f\circ_11_a \Rightarrow f$, how $1_a$ behaves with $n$-ary composition, and what coherence diagrams relating to $n$-ary associativity would we expect?
My second question is more related to example 3.4.5 above and that is how would one define $1$-cell inverses in the unbiased setting? My guess would be the same as the biased setting (a screengrab of the definition given in Hardie, Kamps, and Kieboom's A Homotopy Bigroupoid of a Topological Space is given at the bottom), an inverse functor
$$(-)^{-1} : \mathcal{B}(a,b) \to \mathcal{B}(b,a)$$
with $2$-cells $f^{-1}\circ_1 f \Rightarrow 1_a$ and $f\circ_1 f^{-1} \Rightarrow 1_a$ (this would require an understanding of the first question above). But then I have similar questions to above, how would/should inverses interact with $n$-ary composition, and what coherence diagrams should we expect, again relating to $n$-ary associativity $2$-cells but also the unit coherence $2$-cells?
Thanks for taking the time to read this, and any help is appreciated! I'm more of a topologist/geometer than a category theorist, but trying to wrap my head around this stuff!
https://i.sstatic.net/V0EEo8Nt.png

You are right that the identities are given by the $0$-fold composition $()$, and the coherences give $(f \circ ()) \cong ((f) \circ ()) \cong (f) \cong f$. This is just like the usual correspondence between unbiased monoids (algebras for the free monoid monad) and biased monoids.

@NaïmFavier Thanks for the response! How does $0$-fold composition end up being the empty string? Taken purely from Leinster's definition, this should be defined by a functor $\textbf{1} \to B(a,a)$ which sends the single object $$ to $\circ_0()$ denoted $(*)$ using his notation, effectively picking out a $1$-cell, i.e. an object in $B(a,a)$.

This is just a matter of syntax, but instantiating the notation $(f_n \circ \dots \circ f_1)$ with $n = 0$ gives $()$. This also denotes the empty tuple $(f_1, \dots, f_n)$ with $n = 0$.
